# practice web service calling from iPhone without having web service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to practice Web Service Calling (both SOAP and REST) for iPhone App Development. Problem is i don't have any Web Service implemented for practicing the same.

Any mock URLs (web service) for learning? At which I can have response of all types (like strings, PDFs, images, etc).

I have only basic idea of Web Service Calling from iPhone App. So, purpose is to get good understanding of WebService calling.

I have Mac and Internet, only. Nothing else.

I know this isn't the right place to ask but I could find any help by googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some free opensource web services on the web for your practice. Urls for free webservices are mentioned below.

Note: I am not sure if any of these will give you PDF / IMAGE as an output response of the service.

http://free-web-services.com/

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wscatlist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpfull
Go through the step-by-step tutorial from the below link:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209

Create an app which uses the web service at the following link: http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL, to give the weather of a US city name entered by the user. Use the method "GetWeatherByPlaceName"